# android launcher3 show different icon size in some devices

Tags: android, drawable

android open source launcher3 source code: https://github.com/klinker24/launcher3

When run android launcher3 in vivo phone(see below screenshot), the app icons in desktop show different size.

But in Samsung and Huawei phone, it works fine.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Launcher will process app icon, you can find the code [here createIconBitmap(Drawable icon, Context context, float scale)](https://github.com/klinker24/launcher3/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/launcher3/Utilities.java)

every app size is consistent。
so, what you find may be lead by the different vendor customized. the pic you posted shows the smaller app is Vivo's, may be fit its own launcher.

you can decompile the specific app and check the icon size to figure out.